# Spring Boot 1.4.0 never starts successfully

Tags: spring-boot

Same application works fine with spring boot 1.3.5.RELEASE but when upgraded to 1.4.0.RELEASE, getting the error below -

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.0.RELEASE)

2016-09-18 23:01:20.816  INFO 18220 --- [           main] com.example.SocialApplication            : Starting SocialApplication on badalb-mac.local with PID 18220 (/Users/badalb/codebase/Spring/github/target/classes started by badalb in /Users/badalb/codebase/Spring/github)
2016-09-18 23:01:20.823  INFO 18220 --- [           main] com.example.SocialApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-09-18 23:01:20.925  INFO 18220 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@27eedb64: startup date [Sun Sep 18 23:01:20 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-09-18 23:01:21.719  INFO 18220 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=session; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientContextConfiguration; factoryMethodName=oauth2ClientContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientContextConfiguration] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=session; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$SessionScopedConfiguration$ClientContextConfiguration; factoryMethodName=oauth2ClientContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$SessionScopedConfiguration$ClientContextConfiguration.class]]
2016-09-18 23:01:21.728  INFO 18220 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'oauth2ClientFilterRegistration' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=beanConfig; factoryMethodName=oauth2ClientFilterRegistration; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/example/config/BeanConfig.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$SessionScopedConfiguration; factoryMethodName=oauth2ClientFilterRegistration; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$SessionScopedConfiguration.class]]
2016-09-18 23:01:21.863  WARN 18220 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration$TokenKeyEndpointRegistrar' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2016-09-18 23:01:22.190  WARN 18220 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
2016-09-18 23:01:22.201 ERROR 18220 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SocialApplication.main(SocialApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:189) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

Any Idea??

Comment: Spring Boot thinks you're trying to build a web application, but there's no embedded servlet container. That could be due to many different things. It could be a mistake in your code or a corrupted jar download, for example. I'd check your application's classpath. If everything looks ok, I'd try deleting Maven or Gradle's cache and building and running your app again.

Comment: Can you show how you build, how you start, your pom ?